# Is there a better match for the font Arial than Arial?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, fonts

Unfortunately the Arial font that is present in LibreOffice (which ships with Ubuntu) looks far off from the Arial on a Windows PC. Is there a better match for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Arial using the [ttf-mscorefonts-installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/lucid/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) then you have the very same Microsoft font on your machine.

Arial is merely the Microsoft version of Helvetica, you can try [Liberation Sans](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ttf-liberation) instead, but this is a question of personal taste.

Comment: I didn't install anything, it's the Arial that is present when opening up libre office. How would I install it?

Comment: Id would have been good to mention LibreOffice in your question.  
You would install them using the above-mentioned ttf-mscorefonts-installer...

Comment: Unfortunately your linked website doesn't contain any information on how to install it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu

Comment: nuc@nuc:~$ sudo apt-get ttf-mscorefonts-installer
[sudo] password for nuc: 
E: Invalid Operation ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Comment: you forgot "install"...